# Gibt es das Wort Mülltasche?

Tags: terminology

Gibt es das Wort "Mülltasche"? Wenn ja worauf bezieht sich das?

Comment: "Hat das Wort 'Mülltasche' eine gängige Bedeutung im Deutschen?" trifft es vll. besser, denn sonst darf man alle Beziehungen durchgehen, in denen das Wort 'Müll' eine Tasche (die ja auch mehrere Bedeutungen hat) näher definiert.

Comment: B.: Eine Tragtasche, die aus Müll besteht, eine Hosentasche, in die man seinen Müll tut.

Comment: In welchem **Kontext** hast Du dieses Wort gehört/gelesen?

Comment: @Takkat https://www.google.de/search?q=mülltasche gibt eine Menge möglicher Beispiele.

Comment: @Matthias nicht wir sollten den Kontext über eine Google-Suche erraten müssen. Ein Beispiel in der Frage wäre schon ziemlich hilfreich.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wenn man die Existenz eines Wortes durch dessen Aufführung im Duden definiert, dann gibt es das Wort aktuell nicht. Allerdings ist die Besonderheit des Deutschen, dass sich zusammengesetzte Substantive bilden lassen bis zum "Geht­nicht­mehr". Folglich ist `Mülltasche` ein Wort.

Um ganz genau zu sein: Was ist ein Wort überhaupt? Es ist schwer zu definieren. `kleinste selbstständige sprachliche Einheit von Lautung und Inhalt bzw. Bedeutung`? Nach dieser Definition von `Wort` wäre `Mülltasche` schon ein Wort. Aber perfekt ist sie nicht. Siehe dazu auch den entsprechenden [Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wort) und Abschnitt 8.3.1 [dieses](http://www.christianlehmann.eu/ling/ling_theo/index.html) **sehr** zu empfehlenden Webauftritts.

Gemeint sein kann mit `Mülltasche`

- Eine Tasche, die vom Sprecher als unqualitativ empfunden wird: `So eine Mülltasche`
- Eine Tasche, deren temporärer oder dauerhafter Zweck der Transport von Müll ist

Die `Mülltasche` ist dem `Müllbeutel`, der im Duden steht, sehr ähnlich. Allerdings würde ich folgende Unterschiede festmachen:

- Ein Beutel hat eine sackartige Form, während eine Tasche unzählige Formen haben kann
- Eine Tasche hat häufig Tragegriffe oder Henkel, der Beutel nicht
- Eine Tasche kann auch nur der aufgenähte Teil auf einem Kleidungsstück sein

Comment: Die Aussage zur Qualität ist falsch. Handtaschen gibt es in unzäligen Formen. Turm- und Schwimmbeutel  trägt man auch mit sich herum.

Comment: Nach deiner Definition ist "Mülltasche" kein Wort, da es sich aus den Worten "Müll" und "Tasche" zusammensetzt.

Comment: @userunknown Danke für die Verbesserungen, habs eingearbeitet. Könntest Du vielleicht mehr schreiben als nur "das ist falsch", denn im Allgemeinen kommen mir Taschem schon qualitativer vor als Beutel.

Comment: @Carsten Könntest Du das näher erläutern?

Comment: Es kann nach meiner Definition auch noch ein Wort sein, wenn es sich aus anderen Wörtern zusammensetzt.

Comment: Natürlich kann es das, aber nicht nach der von Dir zitierten Definition, denn dann ist es nicht kleinste Einheit.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Ich denke schon, gemeint ist die kleinste **Einheit** aus Lautung und Bedeutung, welche nur durch diese Kombination zweier Wörter erreicht werden kann, durch die ein neues Wort entsteht. Genau dieses Wort mit exakt dieser Bedeutung lässt sich nicht mehr "kleiner" ausdrücken, deswegen `kleinste`.

Comment: Ist "so eine Mülltasche" nach dieser Definition ein Wort?

Comment: `Eine Tasche hat eine höhere Qualität als ein Beutel` als generelle Aussage ist nur richtig wenn sie für alle Beutel u. Taschen gilt. `Geparden sind schneller als Hasen` kann man wohl sagen, und jeweils gesunde, erwachsene Tiere vor Augen haben. Beutel und Taschen sind aber so heterogen - ein exquisiter Pfeifenbeutel wird vielleicht qualitativ besser sein als eine Plastetasche für Brötchen - allerdings ist fraglich wie man die Qualität von Produkten vergleicht, die qualitativ ganz andere Anforderungen erfüllen müssen. Eine Brötchentasche  aus Seide ist q. nicht besser als eine packpapierne.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Nein, denn "so eine Mülltasche" ist nicht nicht mehr selbstständig, sondern abhängig von einem bestimmten Satzbau: `Wo ist meine "so eine Mülltasche"?` geht nicht. Aber ich weiß, worauf Du hinaus willst, die Definition von einem Wort ist komplex und obige nicht annähernd perfekt. Ich würde bin sehr an anderen Vorschlägen interessiert, siehe auch http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wort

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Sehr empfehlen kann ich auch [Sprachtheorie](http://www.christianlehmann.eu/ling/ling_theo/index.html) -> 8.3.1

Comment: @userunknown Hmm, wäre dann `wertvoller` im preislichen Sinne eine bessere Wahl? Du hast Recht, Qualität passt nicht...

Comment: Ich behaupte nur, dass Du aus *dieser Definition* nicht ableiten kannst, dass "Mülltasche" ein Wort ist, "garbage bag" aber nicht.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Das stimmt. Aber die Definition hat sich auch nur auf deutsche Wörter bezogen. Und wie gesagt, sie ist nicht perfekt...

Comment: Lt. Wiktionary ist ein Beutel eh eine Tasche. Das macht es ganz unsinnig zu sagen Taschen seien besser oder wertvoller.

Answer (score 3):

Als stehenden Begriff gibt es das Wort nicht, aber wie Quasimodo schon sagt, kann man es als Kompositum auffassen.
Ich denke nicht, dass es Menschen / Firmen gibt, die Behältnisse, die zum Transport von Müll konzipiert sind, als `Mülltasche` bezeichnen würden, um diese qualitativ oder anderweitig vom "gewöhnlichen" `Müllbeutel` abzuheben.
Den Begriff `Mülltasche` kenne ich (ebenso wie `Pfandtasche` und `Leerguttasche`) nur im Zusammenhang mit einer Tasche, die ausnahmsweise Müll enthält, beispielsweise beim Picknick. Eine normale Tasche wird also zur `Mülltasche` designiert. Es handelt sich also eher um eine Aufgabe denn eine feste Kategorie von Tasche.
Die pejorative Verwendung wirkt etwas naiv, da könnte ich mir eher `Schrotttasche` oder `Sch***tasche` vorstellen.

Comment: Sehe ich genau so, die unqualitative `Mülltasche` war auch halb als Spaß gemeint =)...

Comment: @Quasimodo Spaß ist hier leider nicht gern gesehen :-( http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/

Comment: Wo doch gerade Deutsche als humorlos gelten...

Comment: @Quasimodo Ich bin sogar Westfale. Ich lache immer nur wenn ich den Müll runterbringe, weil ich dann eh schon im Keller bin.

Comment: ​​​​​​o.O​​​​​​

Comment: Es ist ein Kompositum - das ist nicht der Auffassung freigestellt.

Answer (score 2):

Ich denke, dass eine

> Mülltüte

oder ein

> Müllbeutel

gemeint ist. Speziell, weil Einkaufstüten/-taschen gerne hinterher ein zweite Verwendung zum Sauberhalten des Mülleimers finden, liegt aber "Mülltasche" eigentlich nahe - ist mir aber noch nicht begegnet.

Comment: Meiner Auffassung nach sind Taschen von besserer Qualität (Stoff/Ausarbeitung), und werden daher auch nicht weggeworfen (oder beschmutzt).

Comment: @Carlster: Zustimmung für das Wort "Tasche" allein. Auf den Plastiktüten, die man beim Einkaufen bekommt, steht aber gerne: "Diese Tragetasche ist aus Polyäthylen hergestellt, ist auf der Müllhalde grundwasserneutral und in der Müllverbennung völlig unschädlich also umweltfreundlich." siehe http://www.servowiki.de/images/f/ff/Carrera-tuete-umweltinfo.jpg. Das sind aber genau die von mir gemeinten.

Comment: Keine Regel ohne Ausnahme... Aber wird sie deshalb zur Mülltasche? Oder wirft man bloß etwas in einer Tasche weg?